# Latency under low traffic in Google PubSub

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have noticed that under high load pubsub gives great throughput with pretty low latency. But if I want to send a single message, the latency can often be several seconds. I have used the publish_time in the incoming message to see how long the message spent in the queue and it is usually pretty low. Can't tell if, under very low traffic conditions, a published message doesn't actually get sent by the client libraries right away or if the libraries don't deliver it to the application immediately. I am using asynchronous pull in Python.

Comment: You can play with the PubSub flow control to reduce the latency

Answer (score 0):

There can be several factors that impact latency of low-throughput Pub/Sub streams. First of all, the publish-side client library does wait a period of time to try to [batch messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching) by default. You can get a little bit of improvement by setting the `max_messages` property of the `pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings` to 1, which will ensure that every message is sent as soon as it is ready.

In general, there is also the issue of cold caches in the Pub/Sub service. If your publish rate is infrequent, say, O(1) publish call every 10-15 minutes, then the service may have to load state on each publish that can delay the delivery. If low latency for these messages is very important, our current recommendation is to send a heartbeat message every few seconds to keep all of the state active. You can add an attribute to the messages to indicate it is a heartbeat message and have your subscriber ignore them.

Comment: Those are great ideas. Thank you